# How to enable zeitgeist logging for emacs on ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, emacs, zeitgeist

I would like the files I open in emacs to show up in the dash under the files lens.

As far as I understand zeitgeist is doing the work, but I can't seem to find the emacs zeitgeist data provider that was available for 11.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The emacs datasource can be found on the source code browser. Sadly there is not a recent release (I am working on it) and can be [downloaded here](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~zeitgeist-dataproviders/zeitgeist-datasources/git/view/head:/emacs/zeitgeist.el) by clicking on the "download file" link.

This should work on any version of emacs, irrespective of the version of Ubuntu you are using.

The file can then be used in emacs by adding this line:

```
load-file "/path/to/file/zeitgeist.el"
```

to your .emacs file.

Comment: Hi Manish, Could you please include a little more information about how to get the zeitgeist.el to work with emacs. Or perhaps reference a different answer on askubuntu? Then I'll accept your answer.
Thanks!
Folmer

Comment: Sorry @manish, never mind. I forgot I can edit the answer myself :-)